# ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException, while lazy is false

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate and getting an `ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException` while calling `_factory.BuildSessionFactory();`. I have lazyness disabled by default and have no property that is mapped as lazy. Is the proxy factory needed anyway?

Comment: im too, but it look like i need move to EF or Linq2SQL instead of hibernate :(

Comment: You still need to have a proxy factory available to NHibernate, even if it don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

This config setting is now mandatory, the link below discusses how to set this bit up.

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.html